# Spring 4.3.13.R + JUnit + XML Config

Tags: xml, spring, junit

I have a jar project enclosing all Hibernate-related objects (entities, daos, persistence.xmls). It is a Maven project. It also contains two context.xml files (one for use in Tomcat, the other for JUnit testing).

I have an ancestor class for all my JUnit tests:

```
@ContextConfiguration(
    loader = GenericXmlContextLoader.class,
    locations = { TestAncestor.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT } )
@EnableTransactionManagement
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public abstract class TestAncestor 
    implements Serializable {

    public static final String DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT = "classpath*:context-test.xml";

}
```

The referenced `context-test.xml` file contains all the necessary objects (DataSource, EMF, EM, etc) needed to create a DB/JPA aware context.

But the `@ContextConfiguration` annotation is being ignored the XML altogether. How do I know? Simple: the errors I keep getting are that class X cannot be found for injection point; AND, I put an intentional typo in the .xml file to cause a run time parsing error but it never appears.

WHY is my XML file being ignored? And NO, I cannot use @Configuration and related annotations or Spring Boot.

Comment: Oh, and the top of the XML configuration contains:

    `<context:annotation-config />
   <context:component-scan base-package="a.b.c.db.domain a.b.c.db.dao" />`

Comment: Add a sample of the error and please read [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I also tried:

 @ContextConfiguration(
  loader = GenericXmlContextLoader.class,
  locations = { TestAncestor.DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT } )
 @EnableTransactionManagement
 @SuppressWarnings("serial")
 public abstract class TestAncestor 
  extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests
  implements Serializable {
  
  public static final String DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_CONTEXT = "classpath*:db-dls-dao-context-test.xml";
  
 }

Comment: If I change the path constants to `"file:src/test/resources/META-INF/db-dls-dao-context-test.xml";` it "appears" to work, but then throws an error about not being to look up a JNDI value - which is ONLY defined in the production context xml file. So, despite the absolute path, it is searching and finding the WRONG xml file. WHY?